# how do you subdivision surface, or shade smooth without ruining the object?

Tags: modeling, subdivision-surface, bevel

I want to make a table and a place for its cable management on it. Can you tell me why there's some edge loop or whatever it's called in between the hole once i shade smooth the table? I think it's the reasons why the table can't be that smooth?
I am also do beveling for the edge and I use bool tool for the hole

[image]

[image]

[image: i also do beveling for the edge so it can be smoothen]

Answer (score 2):

These hole cutting tools give an uneven mesh. What i would do is delete those surfaces and make the hole by insetting the surfaces and moving the inset up and down to the holes position. Another options is to loop cut around the hole and face them through to each other. PS to get that square to a circle subdivide it and press shift-ctrl-s and scale it to s sphere

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You should avoid using n-gons and triangles as they are not rendered very well especially when using subdivide modifier, it cud result in strange mesh formation, but anyway you can use the auto smooth tool and control the smoothing angle: [image]